# SQL MINUS operator

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
select deptno  
from emp2  
MINUS  
select deptno 
from dpt  
order by deptno;
```

*the above query returns = No Data Found*

Whereas,

```
select deptno,ename   
from emp2  
MINUS  
select deptno,dname 
from dpt   
order by deptno;
```

*returns all the deptno and ename field values.*

**Can you explain why am I getting all the values of deptno field despite using MINUS operator in the second query?**

```
legend: 
emp is employee table and dpt is department table,
ename is employee name -belonging to emp,
dname is department name -belonging to dpt,
deptno is department no. -common to both
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the first query there is no different `deptno` between tables, in the second you have the same `deptno`, but the names are different

Think about it like this:

Query 1:

```
select deptno  
from emp2  
MINUS  
select deptno 
from dpt  
order by deptno;
```

Example:

```
[1,2,3,4] - [1,2,3,4] = empty
```

Query 2:

```
select deptno,ename   
from emp2  
MINUS  
select dept no,dname 
from dpt  
order by deptno;
```

Example:

```
[(1, 'a'),(2, 'b'),(3, 'c'),(4, 'd')] - 
[(1, 'z'),(2, 'x'),(3, 'u'),(4, 'w')] = 
[(1, 'a'),(2, 'b'),(3, 'c'),(4, 'd')]
```

[MINUS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries004.htm)

> **MINUS** operator, which returns only unique rows returned by the first
>   query but not by the second

Comment: Thank you so much it makes complete sense now :)